# Hide slashes in italic text in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

By default, text between slashes is italicized:

[image]

Is there a way to have org mode hide the slashes while keeping the text italicized?

**UPDATE**

NickD's answer below works great! Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that setting `org-hide-emphasis-markers` to something non-nil will do what you want. The doc string of the variable says:

```
org-hide-emphasis-markers is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
Its value is nil

  This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
  satisfies the predicate ‘booleanp’.

Documentation:
Non-nil mean font-lock should hide the emphasis marker characters.
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you!